Postman. How getting automatically request token using combine username, password, tokenkey
When testing the 'Register User' endpoint in Postman, what methods or techniques can we employ to verify that the requestToken generated adheres to the specified SHA1 hash string pattern,
considering the inclusion of the server-side secret token-key and the construction pattern where the requestToken is formed as username + password + token-key.
i use online generators in SHA1.

Can you show detail step from "online generators in SHA1" to postman call with authorization for requestToken?
